# If iCloud is logged out in iTunes and my iPhone is reset, can I still track it?

Tags: wifi

If iCloud is logged out in iTunes and my iPhone is reset, can I still track it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the answer is no.

To track your phone, you need to have turned on [Find My iPhone](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html) by logging into iCloud and flicking the Find My iPhone switch. If *you* logged out of iCloud, you turn off Find My iPhone, and your phone cannot be tracked. Only you can turn off iCloud unless somebody knows, or guessed, your password and turned it off themselves.

Comment: Okay so what if it got reset do it log out automatic?